# Could not reserve enough space for object heap with 0.13.1 on Windows?

Tags: scala, sbt

I installed sbt `0.13.1` from [http://www.scala-sbt.org](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#) through the msi package.

When I try to start it through a command prompt i get this error

```
C:\Users\megatron>sbt
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

So I followed the recommendation in the [setup notes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Setup-Notes.html)
and added/changed this in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt` file.

```
-Xmx1536M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Xss1M 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

This doesn't help either and I still get the same error.

Comment: Where do you read about `sbtconfig.txt`, in the setup notes you link to I cannot find references to this file?

Comment: I do not use Windows, so just a wild guess: Is `sbt` a batch file? If so, it might look similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735879/using-sbt-in-cygwin-run-the-run-of-play2-cant-send-ctrl-d-to-it) (that's an older version from sbt 0.11); in there you should be able to locate either `JAVA_OPTIONS` or a direct call to `java` where you can add those options. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155325/scala-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-on-ubuntu-12-04) is a similar question for Linux, perhaps it helps.

Comment: I took a look at the sbt.bat which loads sbtconfig.txt for extra options. It even checks for %JAVA_OPTS% in the environment, to use that instead of sbtconfig.txt. %JAVA_OPTS% is not set on my machine.

Comment: Then just try adding your options directly in place of `JAVA_OPTS`

Comment: Just tried this, doesn't help.

Comment: One of the linux question's answers points out a problem with whitespace occurring in the installation path. You also have whitespace in the sbt location; perhaps try installing it in a different location. Also check the [window setup instructions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#windows), especially try creating a simple `sbt.bat` batch file as outlined in that text.

Comment: Whitespace in the path was the problem. Could you please enter this as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should not have white space characters in the installation path to sbt. You have one in `Program Files`. Try installing into a different location.

Comment: This isn't an issue on my machine. If this is causing issues, then you should open a ticket.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the space character was not the root cause, but quite likely the wrong memory settings when on 32-bit machine or using 32-bit JVM (`x86` in the path).

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED, see below]

*workaround for me*:  **first try rebooting Windows**

I've seen this problem in the past on Windows.  Now again with `sbt-0.13.5` on Windows 8.1.

By default the sbt installer installs to `C:/Program Files (x86)/sbt`.  I also tried `C:/sbt` and got the same error while my system appeared to have almost 2G RAM still available.  Next, without changing anything else I rebooted and sbt worked from C:/sbt.  Then I re-installed using the default C:/Program Files (x86)/sbt path and still sbt works.  Of course rebooting isn't a solution.

---

See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303948/68037).  The problem may be that when you are running sbt you are picking up 32-bit JRE (probably via C:/Windows/System32) instead of 64-bit in your path (check with `java -version`).  Apparently the problem is then that although there may be enough memory overall it might not be contiguous that the JVM is requesting.